# How to show time lapse like minutes go

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

What I'm trying to archive is replace the current time from inside td with new time lapse that has past.

Output sample should be 33 minutes ago if current time is 09:33

Comment: Do you mean you want to display just minutes every hour or what do you mean and if that true add example of what you have tried in js

Answer (score 1):

2 options here: the hh:mm readout or the h hours, m minutes readout

```js
let intv
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  intv = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.querySelector('.time')) {
      clearInterval(intv)
      doTimeThing()
    }
  }, 100)
})

function doTimeThing() {
  let d = new Date();
  let ct = (+d.getHours() * 60) + +d.getMinutes();
  let t = document.querySelector('.time').innerText.split(':');
  let ti = (+t[0] * 60) + +t[1];
  let elapsed = ct - ti;
  if (elapsed < 0) {
    console.log('the time has not yet happened')
  } else {
    let eh = ('0' + Math.floor(elapsed / 60)).slice(-2)
    let em = ('0' + elapsed % 60).slice(-2)
    let h = +eh === 1 ? 'hour' : 'hours'
    let m = +em === 1 ? 'minute' : 'minutes'
    let edisp = `${+eh} ${h}, ${+em} ${m} ago`;
    // or if you like this format hh:mm 
    // let edisp = `${eh}:${em} ago`;
    document.querySelector('.time').innerText = edisp;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="time" tabindex="0">09:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is working but how can i replace current time with the minutes ago one? im using in wordpress the $ is giving me issues. thank you

Comment: answer updated with 2 different ways of displaying, and it replaces that TD tag text as well

Comment: @privacymx - did this work for you?

Comment: ok no problem and thanks, i can't make it work for wordpress my error at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):854)  LINE IS let t = document.querySelector('.timeago').innerText.split(':');

Comment: ok, I updated it to wait for the page to load first. Can you try that. Thanks

Comment: i keep getting  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Comment: ok, your table must be getting written to the DOM  at some point after load. This new revised answer will check for it until it's there, then do the magic. Try that.